# Ui-Bootstrap Datepicker javascript error : Type Error has no method 'getFullYear'

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to set a default date for ui bootstrap datepicker. The dates are coming from json and are in Unix timestamp format.

```
[ 
    { "type": "date", "name": "date 1", "value": 1375907474 },
    { "type": "date", "name": "date 2" },
    { "type": "date", "name": "date 3", "value": 1378590263 }
]
```

inside a directive, i am trying to convert the date and to bind it to ng model

```
scope.dt = $filter('date')(scope.required.value*1000);
```

but it gives a javascript error :

```
TypeError: Object Sep 7, 2013 has no method 'getFullYear'
```

here is a plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/a9gfH8?p=preview

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are seeing is the result of this:

```
"Sep 7, 2013".getFullYear()
```

What you want is this:

```
new Date("Sep 7, 2013").getFullYear()
```

Somewhere you're passing angular a string instead of a date object.